How to install plprofiler via pip on Alpine linux
I'm trying to install plprofiler on my Apline Linux like this:
apk add python3 py3-pip \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install plprofiler plprofiler-client psycopg2-binary

The docs don't mention installing the plprofiler itself via pip at all, only plprofiler-client, but I can't use RPM in Alpine linux (can I?), and the first mentioned install method points at a website that doesn't seem to exist anymore.
It looks like there at least one more step is missing to install the extension properly: when I run CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "plprofiler";, I get this error back:
[0A000] ERROR: extension "plprofiler" is not available Detail: Could not open extension control file "/usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/plprofiler.control": No such file or directory. Hint: The extension must first be installed on the system where PostgreSQL is running.

I've already reported an issue in the repository, but it doesn't seem to be too active. Can somebody please shed some light on this?

Try to get it running with a regular PostgreSQL installation before you daddle with containers.

How would that help me figure out how to run it in my Alpine-based container where I ultimately need it?

Just install Alpine Linux on a virtual machine. Then install the PostgreSQL extension. Once you know how to do that, it should be simple to translate that to instructions for building a container.

I'm unsure how using a virtual machine differs from a set of commands issued in the Alipne-based Docker file, which runs in a virtual machine per se.

For one, you can debug any error you encounter. Your mileage may vary, but it works for me. I need to be able to do it by hand, then it is easy to write an RPM Specfile.

Ah, now I see what you mean. I don't debug the installation process in a Dockerfile. I usually start a plain image, log into it and start doing what I need to do, updating the Dockerfile with the commands that I have executed manually and are working. But that's all irrelevant to the intended topic of the question, "How to install plprofiler on Apline linux". The Dockerfile is unimportant; it was meant to illustrate the (only) steps I have done to get to that error. I see it may be shifting the angle people view this question, I'll get rid of the Docker reference. Thanks.

I see; so we are on the same page here. Looking at the error, that means that you didn't install the extension in the correct directory. Perhaps you should build the extension from source.

I opted to switch the distro to Debian, where the package is readily available. Sadly, the profiler didn't give me the answer I had hoped for. It seems it's only interpreting whatever EXPLAIN ANALYZE would tell me, just with some GUI.

No, PLProfiler gives you a flame graph of which function calls which, and how much time is spent where. Quite useful if you have a forest of functions calling each other, and pretty useless otherwise.

I stand corrected, what I wrote is not accurate. It does show what you say. I just hoped it would tell me more: I have a function that returns a table and sometimes calls itself recursively. I wanted to find out which calls take the most time. Instead, I know how many times the function is called and how much time was spent on it. It's different from what the explain query does, but it didn't give me the answer I sought. I'm also fully open to the fact that I may be using it wrong. Either way, it was worth the try and Thanks Laurenz to take the time to reply here.

I have reached out to the author of plprofiler, asking whether there is any way to install the server extension via pip. Here is the answer I received, emphasis is mine:

The server side extension is available as RPM (or DEB) from PGDG. Pip is not supposed to install binaries in the PostgreSQL share dir. From what I can see all PG versions from 12 to 16 are supported.

This left me with two options: stay with Alpine Linux and compile the extension from the source, or switch to another distribution.
Considering this is for local development using Docker, I simply switched to the base Docker image built on Debian and installed it using apt without any issues: apt install postgresql-15-plprofiler plprofiler was enough to get rid of the error when calling create extension if not exists  plprofiler;
